# Android: Camera Intent Won't Launch On Emulator

Tags: java, android

I have a simple program that uses the built in camera app. Not sure why, but all of a sudden it won't work on the emulator. It still works fine on my actual physical device though. I should not that the actual camera 'app' on the emulator launches fine and does the whole checkered background green squre thing. Any ideas?

```
        if (id == R.id.action_picture) {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            File mSelfieFile = null;

            try {
                mSelfieFile = SelfieBitmapHelper.createFileName();
                mSelfiePhotoPath = mSelfieFile.getAbsolutePath();
            } catch (IOException ex) {  }

            if (mSelfieFile != null) {
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(mSelfieFile));
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, PHOTO_REQUEST);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Please define "won't work".

Comment: Nothing. I click on the action bar icon that should launch the camera app and nothing happens. On my physical device it launches the built in camera app no problem.

Comment: Are you using the google-supplied emulators? I have found them a bit flakey sometimes. Have had good results with genymotion and they start up a lot faster :-)

Comment: YEah just the one that's with Android Studio. Since it works fine on both my Nexus 5 and Nexus 7, I'm chalking it up to a weird beta glitch. It's just weird because I've been working on this app for a few days now using the emulated camera with no problem, I finished with that portion of the app a while ago and haven't touched it since. Moved on to messing with content providers and things to store the images. But the actual picture taking part hasn't changed. No idea what I did to 'break' it.